# How to terminate one application from another application

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, mfc

There are three applications main.exe (C++), one.exe (C++) and two.exe (.net).

I want to terminate one.exe and two.exe from main.exe if they are running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to effectively kill a process in C++ (Win32)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916574/how-to-effectively-kill-a-process-in-c-win32)

Comment: Tell us more about these programs. The answers below while correct are not necessarily appropriate. `WM_CLOSE` works only for GUI programs and even then sending `WM_CLOSE` may not actually terminate the program but just trigger an "Are you sure?" dialog. `TerminateProcess` is rather crude and may cause all kinds of problems, imagine your program is in the middle of updating a database and it gets suddenly killed; this may leave your database in an inteterminate state or even corrupt it. Do you have the source code of `one.exe`and `two.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

Normal GUI applications? Just send them `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: That doesn't terminate a process. It's a request, which any application can happily ignore.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Process ID for one.exe and two.exe you can get process handle and use `TerminateProcess` function. Here is the code sample:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, dwProcessId);
if (hProcess == NULL)
{
  return;
}

UINT uExitCode;
BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, uExitCode);
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a GUI application, you may send a WM_CLOSE message to the other application.

Or if you want to kill the other process, then use TerminateProcess() function.