# kill a process given its PID

Tags: c, pid, kill

I never programmed in C before, but I need a C program that kills a process given its PID. I know this question was a lot asked, but I encounter a compilation error that I don't understand. Here is the code built with the things that I could find on the Internet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    if (argc != 2 ) return 1;

    int pid = atoi (argv[1]);
    kill (pid, SIGINT);

    return 0;
}
```

And the logs:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in processKiller (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c "D:\.Ce PC\Desktop\ws processKiller\processKiller\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
D:\.Ce PC\Desktop\ws processKiller\processKiller\main.c: In function 'main':
D:\.Ce PC\Desktop\ws processKiller\processKiller\main.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atoi' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     int pid = atoi (argv[1]);
     ^
D:\.Ce PC\Desktop\ws processKiller\processKiller\main.c:9:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'kill' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     kill (pid, SIGINT);
     ^
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\processKiller.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `main':
D:/.Ce PC/Desktop/ws processKiller/processKiller/main.c:9: undefined reference to `kill'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Thanks.

Comment: For `atoi` you need *stdlib.h*

Answer (score 1):

`kill` is a POSIX function. Since you are on Windows, you will need to find how to kill a process using WINAPI. This is a bit more complicated but this should get you started: [How to effectively kill a process in C++ (Win32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916574/how-to-effectively-kill-a-process-in-c-win32)

Comment: I think MinGW will make most or all of POSIX available, I guess `kill()` will be translated internally my MinGW.

Comment: I don't mentioned it, but I need to kill the process "softly", with SIGINT.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I hadn't considered this and you may be correct.