# Is there a function to end a child process?

Tags: c, winapi, operating-system, kill-process

I am creating an operating system and I created a child process using C with this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fptr;

    // Open a file in read mode
    fptr = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

    // Store the content of the file
    char myString[100];
    fgets(myString, 100, fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION ni;
    STARTUPINFO li;
    ZeroMemory(&li, sizeof(li));
    li.cb = sizeof(li);

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, "child_process.exe", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &li, &ni)) {
        // Parent process
        WaitForSingleObject(ni.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(ni.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(ni.hThread);
    } else {
        // Child process
    }
    
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("(%d) WARNING: These processes are vital for the OS:\n", pid);
    printf("(%d) %d\n", pid, pid);
    printf("(%d) %s\n\n\n", pid, myString);
    return 0;
}
```

And I could not end the child process. ***I do not want to use signals as they are too complex and I am a beginner.***

I tried using `return 0;` and it did not work, the process was still running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to effectively kill a process in C++ (Win32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916574/how-to-effectively-kill-a-process-in-c-win32)

Comment: No I am using c,

Comment: Do you want it to end in a controlled way or don't you care if it's in the middle of doing something important? If you don't care, you could use [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)

Comment: As I said I am a beginner I do not understand TerminateProcess

Comment: Creating an operating system is *far* more advanced than understanding signals.  Creating an OS is a laudable goal, and one of the first tasks you might want to consider is learning how signals work.

Comment: I am not making a full operating system. I am trying to make a os that can at least can do the following things:
Making a process
Killing a process
Making a file
Deleting a file

Comment: @AdamAhmed What you are creating is more like a command shell of some sort. Those run on top of operating systems. `TerminateProcess` does what you want: It kills a process.

Comment: TerminateProcess is in c++ not c. I need it to be c

Comment: `TerminateProcess` _is_ C. It works in C++ too though. Your comment `// Child process` is wrong btw. If `CreateProcess` returns zero, it means that it failed.

Comment: I could not understand TerminateProcess

Comment: Ok, then you need to read about it until you do. There's no way around that.

Comment: Your code sample suggests you're trying to use Windows's CreateProcess the same way someone might use a unix-style fork.  Those are very different models of process creation and not really interchangeable.  I suggest you search for a tutorial on process creation for Windows (or whichever platform you intend to build on).  If working through that doesn't resolve your issue regrading terminating a process, you'll be able to post a question that gets more helpful responses.

Comment: `CreateProcess()` does not fork the code. After `CreateProcess()` exits, your code is still running in the parent process. The child process is completely independent. The `PROCESS_INFORMATION` contains `HANDLE`'s to the child process and its main thread. You can pass that process handle to `TerminateProcess()` if needed.

Comment: Classic beginner mistake of running before you can walk.

Answer (score 0):

You terminate a process by calling [`TerminateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess). Doing so will terminate the target process if the caller holds sufficient privileges. This works for any process, not just child processes.

But before you go there, you first need to understand how [`CreateProcessW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) works. The documentation explains the semantics in detail. The return value, in particular, differs from what the code in question assumes.